# IntelliJ go back after Command + Click

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

For IntelliJ IDE:

How do I go back to the code that I was reading after I clicked:

`Command + Click` for IntelliJ.

Same question for *after I found usage and want to go back*.

**OS** is `macOS`.

Comment: Answer that worked for me: Just open the `Navigation` menu from the top. Information is hiding there in plain sight :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go Back on ***Windows/Linux***:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>

On ***MacOS***:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

The same is possible from the menu:

> Navigate > Back

---

*Same question for after I found usage and want to go back.*

Just go back to editor from usage window:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Go back to editor and hide find window:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>

It works for hiding other recent window too (Project, Run ...)

Also, keymap reference is available:

> Help > Keymap Reference

Comment: My default IntelliJ on mac had different options. However, the key is look for the keymap under `Navigation` menu. Information is hiding there in plain sight :-/

Comment: One can go to keymap mapping on vscode and use cntrl + [.. I personalyy prefer it over cntrl + alt + left